# Are fast Anonymous functions automatic now?

Tags: function, julia

Now that fast anonymous functions are native to julia, do I still have to use the decorator, or is it automatically implemented. Also when I pass a function as an argument into another function, can I static type it? What can I do to improve the run speed.

Comment: Which decorator are you talking about?

Comment: the macro from FastAnonymous @anon

Comment: FastAnonymous? No, that's many years ago. You don't need that, and they probably don't work anyway.

Comment: so it's automatic? I just wanted to make sure. Also is there a solution for efficently passing functions as arguments for other functions I don't think FastAnonymous was ever a solution for that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Anonymous are now fast, and have been for several years. You can efficiently pass them as arguments to other functions. That's what anonymous functions are for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FastAnonymous is definitely not necessary anymore. Here's how you can verify this yourself:

```
julia> @noinline g(f, x) = f(x)  # prevent inlining so you know it's general
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> h1(x) = g(identity, x)
h1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> h2(x) = g(sin, x)
h2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype h1(1)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(h1, false)
  x::Int64

Body::Int64
1 ─ %1 = Main.g(Main.identity, x)::Int64
└──      return %1

julia> @code_warntype h2(1)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(h2, false)
  x::Int64

Body::Float64
1 ─ %1 = Main.g(Main.sin, x)::Float64
└──      return %1

julia> h3(x) = g(z->"I'm a string", x)
h3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype h3(1)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(h3, false)
  x::Int64
  #9::getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10"))

Body::String
1 ─      (#9 = %new(Main.:(##9#10)))
│   %2 = #9::Core.Compiler.Const(getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10"))(), false)
│   %3 = Main.g(%2, x)::Core.Compiler.Const("I'm a string", false)
└──      return %3
```

In every case Julia knows the return type, and that requires that it "understand" what your function-argument is doing. Moreover:

```
julia> m = first(methods(g))
g(f, x) in Main at REPL[1]:1

julia> m.specializations
Core.TypeMapEntry(Core.TypeMapEntry(Core.TypeMapEntry(nothing, Tuple{typeof(g),typeof(identity),Int64}, nothing, svec(), 1, -1, MethodInstance for g(::typeof(identity), ::Int64), true, true, false), Tuple{typeof(g),typeof(sin),Int64}, nothing, svec(), 1, -1, MethodInstance for g(::typeof(sin), ::Int64), true, true, false), Tuple{typeof(g),getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10")),Int64}, nothing, svec(), 1, -1, MethodInstance for g(::getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10")), ::Int64), true, true, false)
```

This is a bit hard to read, but if you look carefully you'll see that `g` has been compiled for 3 inputs:

- `Tuple{typeof(identity), Int64}`
- `Tuple{typeof(sin), Int64}`
- `Tuple{getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10")),Int64}`

(The compiled versions also take `g` itself as an extra argument, for reasons having to do with things like the internal implementation of keyword-argument handling, but let's ignore that for now.) The last one is the generated name for the type implementing the anonymous function. What this shows you is that each function has its own type, which is the reason why passing functions as arguments is fast.

For the gurus, there is one other factor that can come in to play: because type inference is subject to the unsolvable [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), there are circumstances where inference will decide that this is all getting too complex and abort "early." In such cases (which are relatively rare), it can help to force the compiler to specialize against a particular argument. In our example, that would mean declaring `g` as

```
@noinline g(f::F, x) where F = f(x)
```

rather than

```
@noinline g(f, x) = f(x)
```

That `::F` is normally unnecessary and appears useless, but you can use it as a compiler-hint to increase the amount of effort used to infer the result. I don't recommend doing that by default (it makes your code a bit harder to read), but if you see weird performance problems it's one thing to try.

Comment: awesome thank you! No sure I understood it all but definitely helpful.